# Why Function Pointer rather than Calling function Directly

Tags: c

I have come across the function pointers. I know understand how this works. But i am not pretty sure, in what situation it will use. After some google and other search in Stack Overflow. I came know to know that it will use in two case

> when callback mechanism is used
>
> Store a array of functions, to call dynamically.

In this case also, why don't we call function directly. In the call back Mechanism also, as particular events occur, callback pointer is assigned to that function(Address). Then that is called. Can't we call function directly rather than using the function pointer. Can some some one tell me, what is the exact usage of Function pointer and in what situation.

Comment: Function pointers are used when you *don't know ahead of time* which function is going to be called.  You cannot pass functions as arguments to another function, you can only pass function pointers.

Comment: Simple example would be a predicate.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at functions needing a callback, like

[`bsearch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsearch.3.html) or [`qsort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) for the comparator, [`signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) for the handler, or others.

Also, how would you want to program other openly-extensible mechanisms, like C++-like virtual-dispatch (`vptr`-table with function-pointers and other stuff)?

In short, function-pointers are used for making a function generic by making parts of the behavior user-defined.

Comment: Is there any processing speed differ?calling function directly or function pointer to that function

Comment: Yes, an indirect call is *in general* less efficient. Though don't obsess about it, unless you are really sure (measure!) that's the bottleneck. Also, when you have to use it, you just do.

Answer (score 3):

One of the situation when function pointers would be useful is when you are trying to implement callback functions.

For example, in a server that I've been implementing in C and libevent accepts a message from clients and determine what to do. Instead of defining hundreds of switch-case blocks, I store function pointer of function to be called in a hash table so the message can be directly mapped to the respective function.

[Event handling in libevent](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref4_event.html) API(read about event_new()) also demonstrates the usefulness of having function points in APIs such that users can define their own behaviour given a certain situation and need not to modify the master function's code, which creates flexibility while maintaining certain level of abstraction. This design is also widely used in the Kernel API.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> In the call back Mechanism also, as particular events occur, callback pointer is assigned to that function(Address).

Callback functions are registered at a very different place than where the callback functions are called.

A simple example:

In a GUI, the place where you register a function when a button is pressed is your toplevel application setup. The place where the function gets called is the implementation of the button. They need to remain separate to allow for the user of the button to have the freedom of what they wish to do when a button is pressed.

In general, you need a function pointer when the pointer needs to be stored to be used at a future time.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a callback situation, including interrupt driven code, a sequence of call backs or interrupts may occur for a single logical process. Say you have a set of functions like step1(), step2(), ... , to perform some process where a common callback is being used to step through a sequence. The initial call sets the callback to step1(), when step1() is called, it changes the pointer to function to step2() and initiates the next step. When that step completes, step2() is called, and it can set a pointer to function to step3(), and so on, depending on how many steps it takes to perform the sequence. I've mostly used this method for interrupt driven code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use function pointers just to make (as I see it) the code more legible, and easier to change. But this is a matter of taste, there is no one 'correct' way. It's possible that the function pointer code will be slower, but probably only slightly and of course as far as performance goes it's always a matter of measuring, and usually more a matter of choosing better algorithms than of micro-optimisation.

One example is when you have two functions, with identical and long argument lists and sometimes you want to call one and sometimes the other. You could write

```
if ( condition)
{ one( /* long argument list */);
}
else
{ other( /* long argument list */);
}
```

or you could write

```
(condition ? one : other)(/* long argument list */);
```

I prefer the second as there is only one instance of the long argument list, and so it's easier to get right, and to change.

Another case is implementing state machines; one could write

```
switch( state)
{ case STATE0: state = state0_fun( input); break; 
// etc
}
```

or

```
typedef int (*state_f)( void*);
state_f statefs[] = { state0_fun /* etc */}

state = statefs[ state](input);
```

Again I find the second form more maintainable, but maybe that's just me.